# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined error with React and Auth0

Tags: authentication, meteor, reactjs, auth0

I've been getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined with React and Auth0` that I have not been able to debug.

I've followed the **auth0** and **react** [tutorial](https://manage.auth0.com/#/applications/dUDETu2maxvyK7hbpyGgFYd1RaW5Zxkp/quickstart), but still cannot get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
### login.jsx

/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />

import * as React from "react"

import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock'
import Button from './button.jsx'

export default class Login extends React.Component {


    componentDidMount() {
        this.lock = new Auth0Lock('AUTH0-CLIENT_ID', 'AUTH0_CLIENT_DOMAIN')`
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                Login Today
                <Button lock={this.lock}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



## button.jsx
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />


import React from 'react'

export default class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
}

  login() {
    console.log(this.props.lock)
    this.props.lock.show(); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.login}>Login with Auth</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(this.props.lock)`? Probably login() is called before this.props.lock is defined?

Comment: I get an `undefined`. I tried to put it on a `componentWillMount(){}` but I get an `Invalid ref violation` error

Comment: Just a Hunch: You are probably losing the `this` in `this.login`. Can you try doing `onClick={ e => this.login(e) }`